# MSChart X and Y Axis Labels Overlap at origin

Tags: c#, mschart

Using C# and the Control MSChart.

When I set the `Min`, `Max` and `Interval` properties of the X and Y axis everything comes out as it should save that the labels nearest the origin overlap. If I set the `IsMarginVisible` to *true* but still calculate the interval myself the problem disappears as the X axis labels are now placed low enough that they do not impede those of the Y axis. What property controls this offset?

I have a similar problem if I show Axis Arrows: the arrowhead and one of the labels overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable smart labels. When smart labels are enabled, the Chart control first attempts to reposition an overlapping data point label near the data point itself. If it fails, the Chart control then moves the data point label to a valid free space and draws a line to link the label with the data point.

```
   chart1.Series["Default"].SmartLabelStyle.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. Explain _why_ it is a solution.

Comment: @stefan I hope thats taken care of.